# Each Data Node in a Hadoop cluster is constantly reading disk

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

Some time ago I found out that each of our data nodes is constantly reading disks at ~10M/s accumulated speed. I found it out with `iotop` util.

What I've done so far to diagnose it:

- I tried to stop different services on a cluster, but it only stops when I stop hdfs service completely
- I checked the logs of a data node, but can only see some `HDFS_WRITE`s operation happening every 1-2 minutes, nothing about reading the data. I checked during idle time of course

Some info on our system:

- we're using a CDH distro, 5.8 now, but the problem started several versions ago
- no running jobs in YARN at that moment
- the issue is here for several months 24/7 and it wasn't there before

My prime suspect for now is some auditing process at CDH. Unfortunately I couldn't find any good documentation on administration of these processes.

Here is an information on a data node process from `ps -ef` output:

```
hdfs     58093  6398 10 Oct11 ?        02:56:30 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dproc_datanode -Xmx1000m -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,RFAAUDIT -Dsecurity.audit.logger=INFO,RFAS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-hdfs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop-cmf-hdfs-DATANODE-hadoop-worker-03.srv.mycompany.org.log.out -Dhadoop.home.dir=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.2-1.cdh5.8.2.p0.3/lib/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hdfs -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Djava.library.path=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.2-1.cdh5.8.2.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -server -Xms1073741824 -Xmx1073741824 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/lib/cmf/service/common/killparent.sh -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode
```

I'll be really grateful for any clues on an issue.

Comment: what other nodes are you running on the box that has datanode?

Comment: I hope no one/cron/script is running hdfs rebalancer which balances the data from one data node to other data nodes.

Comment: @PreetiKhurana when I run the balancer it exits immediately with a "cluster is balanced" message

Comment: @RatnakarPawar do you mean services? We run HBase for example, but as I said iotop points exactly to datanode process, so it should be something with HDFS.

Comment: ok, put a wireshark/tcupdump on the datanode port and see where the data is coming from. Trace back to the source ip and source port and see which application accounts for it